# `mpl::plus< mpl::int_<1>, mpl::int_<2> >::type` not the same type as `mpl::int_<3>`?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

The code below reproduces a behavior I really don't understand of the boost MPL library:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main() {
  typedef mpl::int_<1> one;
  typedef mpl::int_<2> two;
  typedef mpl::int_<3> three;
  // The following line breaks compilation...
  // static_assert( is_same< mpl::plus<one,two>::type, three >::type::value, "Not the same type");
  // ...while this works
  static_assert( mpl::plus<one,two>::type::value == three::value , "Not the same value");
  return 0;
}
```

The question I have is: **why `mpl::plus<one,two>::type` is not the same type as `three`?**

I ran into this issue while trying to solve the exercises at the end of chapter 3 of 
[C++ Template Meta-Programming](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/). I already tried to peek at `<boost/mpl/plus.hpp>` and the includes therein, but the code was too complicated for me to be understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of `plus` is only guaranteed to be an integral constant. You have no guarantee over it's exact type, hence your assert *is allowed* to fail.

The exact types are this:

```
mpl::plus<one,two>::type == mpl_::integral_c<int, 3>
three == foo<mpl_::int_<3> >
```

This is unintuitive. One problem is that `plus<int_, int_>` theoretically can return a `integral_c` where the first argument has a larger capacity then `int_` in case of overflow.

For debugging a `type printer` can be useful:

```
template<typename> print; // undefined instantiation leads to error with name
print<three> x; // nice error message
```

Comment: Thanks for the `template<typename> struct print;` tip!

Comment: @Massimiliano There is also `mpl::print` but that seems broken on at least `gcc`. Something that does not abort compilation would be a lot nicer.

Comment: as a sidenote, this si registered as an issue in boost Trac. So we know it's an issue :)